# How to enable ssl in grpc with java using keystore

Tags: java, spring, grpc, grpc-java

New to gRPC using java and I am not able to find a way how to enable ssl while using truststore and clientstore. I have been able to enable ssl by pointing to individual certificates but not using the truststore. Any leads will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to convert the `KeyStore` for CA cert (truststore) to a `TrustManagerFactory` and the `KeyStore` for client cert/key (clientstore) to a `KeyManagerFactory`.

The former can be done with

```java
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
tmf.init(truststore);
```

and the latter can be done with

```java
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientstore, password);
```

Then, if you are using Netty transport, you can build the `SslContext` with

```java
SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(tmf).keyManager(kmf).build();
```

See its `SslContextBuilder` [Javadoc](https://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder.html).

Lastly, build gRPC channel with

```java
NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

---

If you are using Okhttp transport, you need to build the `SSLSocketFactory` with

```java
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = context. getSocketFactory()
```

and build gRPC channel with

```java
OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();
```

Comment: how does the channel get set in the server. I build my server using ServerBuilder and not see method to set the channel.
 server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port).
 useTransportSecurity(certFile, keyFile).addService(this).build().start();

Comment: Channel is built with its own builder (e.g, `ManagedChannelBuilder` or transport-specific ones). Server applications build the server while client applications build the channel, you do not "set" the channel from server.